# Are these motors compatible?

Tags: electric-motor

I'm trying to replace a motor in a Miele S5580 Luna canister vacuum.

After disassembly, I found that the OEM motor has the following specs:

```
Type   MRG 742/81-42/2
Part   06514630
Nr     061954
     
~120V  HS-gepr
```

(It also has a model # on it, 05782500; not sure how this differs from the part #.)

I've found [this replacement](https://www.ebay.com/itm/133583911150?hash=item1f1a38b8ee:g:EhgAAOSwaQdfuWJh) on Ebay with *slightly* different specs. It claims to be taken from an S558, which is a different model of vacuum, but seems to be the same generation or line.

```
Type   MRG 722/81-42/2
Part   05709490
Nr     043088
     
~120V  HS-gepr
```

I presume that the relevant part is the "Type": MRG 722/81-42/2 vs. MRG 742/81-42/2. Since I don't know much about motors, here's my question: **Are these two motors functionally compatible?**

(If that's something that can be determined from this data.)

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I should improve the question!

Comment: it depends on what the numbers mean

Comment: Measure the dimensions : length, diameter, shaft dia, thread length etc etc

Comment: @jsotola That's what I'm asking :) SolarMike Sadly can't measure the one on Ebay. But it looks like it would almost certainly fit. I just don't know if they'll be functionally compatible.

Comment: It appears to me it would be better to get a new one, which will come with a warranty etc. I do not know the price of your model but I know they are pricey.

Comment: @GIl Thanks. I've been slowly coming round to that conclusion too...

Comment: Those are not specifications. Those are part numbers.

Comment: Those are not standard NEMA type motors that the type of motor specify the frame size and mounting pattern, shaft size etc. it is possible the first number could be wattage? And the others be the frame, mounting and shaft size. Many small motors are OEM so you have to purchase them at 2x or more from the manufacture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair is off topic here.

Comment: imo, a downvote and a close vote are different tracks to different solutions, not mutually compatible. A closed question is intended to persist, like a duplicate, as a useful record of what has been asked in order to bring up the average quality of future questions. A downvote leads to deletion (or pseudo-deletion to those with lower rep) and is intended to mark a question whose quality or intent is so damaging to the site that it's better for it to be invisible. I think, two years down the line, that this question is a good candidate for the close track rather than the downvote/delete track.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at configured assemblies, not just the DC motor.  Each manufacturer has a different naming convention, and Meile is going to order the configured motor assembly they designed into each model. So offhand, it is most likely not a direct fit you would need to find out from the manufacturer what the 742 represents if you want to verify.  Sometimes it's the case size, shaft length, poles/terminals, etc.  Manufacturers don't often use two different parts when they could have consolidated to one.

Answer (score 0):

I bought one on Amazon and it did not function when plugged in. I don’t know why. The motor looks identical. S5580 needs a 1200 watt motor not a 1600 watt unit thus you need a 742/120 not a 722

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please [edit] your answer to provide some additional clarity - what does your vacuum purchase have to do with the OPs? What does the motor look identical to? Your last sentence seems like it would stand on its own as a good answer, but it could use some supporting evidence to back it up. Also, sorry you got a bum unit - you did pack it right back up for return to BigRiver for refunt/replacement and didn't start disassembling it trying to fix a brand new item, didn't you?